# ext js update chart pie after filter

Tags: extjs, filter, pie-chart

I am having a problem with filtering my chart fields.
I have a chart pie that contains some fields.
The user can filter the chart pie and select which fields he wants to see.
The problem is that if the pie has 8 fields and the user selects only 6 fields, the filter only filters the data but does not filter the fields as well.

For example, if I have the fields

```
{name:'Asia','data1':9, sex:'Male'},
{name:'Africa','data1':2, sex:'Male'},
{name:'Europe','data1':5, sex:'Female'},
{name:'USA','data1':3, sex:'Male'},
```

and I want to filter Asia, Africa and Europe, I can still see the USA name fields (without the data).

The code:

```
storeIng.filterBy(function(record,id){ 
    var fieldName = record.get('name')
    for(var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        if (fields[i] === fieldName) 
            return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

I add screen shots as well
before
http://i45.tinypic.com/1eq74i.jpg
after
http://i45.tinypic.com/1z1zofq.jpg

Comment: Please show more code. In what context do you call the filterBy function?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not given much code, try this code for reference and see where is the mistake. The filterBy function that you have written seems to be all right. This can also help others reading this if they are having problems in filtering store data.

```
    Ext.onReady(function(){

var data=[
            {name:'Asia','data1':9, sex:'Male'},
            {name:'Africa','data1':2, sex:'Male'},
            {name:'Europe','data1':5, sex:'Female'},
            {name:'USA','data1':3, sex:'Male'}
        ]

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.JsonStore', {
fields: ['name', 'data1','sex'],
data:data
              });

              store.filterBy(function(record,id){
if(record.get('name')==="Asia")
    return true;
             })

    Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
width: 500,
height: 350,
animate: true,
store: store,
theme: 'Base:gradients',
series: [{
    type: 'pie',
    angleField: 'data1',
    showInLegend: true,

    highlight: {
        segment: {
            margin: 20
        }
    },
    label: {
        field: 'name',
        display: 'rotate',
        contrast: true,
        font: '18px Arial'
    }
}]
         });

     });
```